# ShouldJs Typescript issues with promises

Tags: typescript, promise, should.js

I'm getting a compile error in typescript with shouldjs only when trying to use the `.rejected() / .fufilled()` syntax

```
Promise.resolve().should // is fine, is an Assertion
Promise.resolve().should.rejected // is fine, is a Function
Promise.resolve().should.rejected() // TS2349 Cannot invoke expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type Promise<any> has no compatible call signatures
```

I tried casting to `PromisedAssertion` like this: `(<PromisedAssertion>Promise.resolve())` or `(Promise.resolve() as PromisedAssertion)` to no effect. How can I fix this?

`.should` works fine otherwise

Comment: Looks like a bug in `should.js`, since the typings I get with `npm install` incorrectly set `rejected` and `fulfilled` as `Promise<any>`.

Comment: Create an issue with full details. I could not repro this.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/shouldjs/should.js/issues/176 and https://github.com/lev-kuznetsov/should-promise-typescript-issue

Answer (score 0):

Created an issue against should repo, in the meantime casting to `any` works